# Make button tapped only once - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making timer. I cannot figure out how to make start button tapped only once as it is starting to count. And at stop button timer.invalidate() does not work

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(W1ViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBOutlet weak var stopOutlet: UIButton!

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
    seconds = 30
    label.text = "\(seconds)"
    timer.invalidate()
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just disable the button

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    stopOutlet.isEnabled = false
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(W1ViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Then re-enable when needed:

```
stopOutlet.isEnabled = true
```

[UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) extends [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol). UIControl provides this and alot more functionality to all controls.